# What does the slash mean in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql

What does the slash character mean in this query? This is being used with a MySql database.

```
SELECT Channel, COUNT(Channel) AS Total, COUNT(Channel) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserClicks WHERE (Date > '2009-12-1' AND Date < '2010-1-1') AND RoleType='member' ) AS Percent FROM UserClicks WHERE (Date > '2009-12-1' AND Date < '2010-1-1') AND RoleType='member' GROUP BY Channel ORDER BY Total DESC
```

**Update:** sorry, stupid question! =P

Comment: Hey - at least you asked because you were curious as opposed to just shrugging your shoulders and letting it pass as just some magic...  :D

Comment: Where else can you have such a question answered 5 times in less than 60 seconds?

Comment: While the division is obvious, I am rather suspicious of the overall field being called 'percent' when in fact it looks more like a proportion (0..1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a division sign.  It's dividing two numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It is the division operator.

Answer (score 2):

It is the division operator. See the manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_divide

Answer (score 1):

It literally means "divided by".

Answer (score 1):

It's the division operator